# Continuous with no left derivative

Tags: calculus

I'm sure there are many examples for this, but I just can't find it. What is  an example of a function continuous at point $a$, but has no left derivative at point $a$?

Comment: The Weierstrass function is an example of one such function.

Comment: Given your question, it could be interesting to have a right derivative, but no left derivative. Take $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\geq 0$. And see what happens at $0$.

Comment: @julien In that case, wouldn't $f$ have a left derivative? $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}x\sin(1/x) = 0$.

Comment: Oops, I meant $x\sin(1/x)$...

Comment: @julien Sure, that's what I thought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, simple absolute value functions won't work since you want the failure of a unilateral derivative. Consider $f(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0.$ At $x = 0,$ this function is neither left (finitely or infinitely) differentiable nor right (finitely or infinitely) differentiable. A nice way of seeing this geometrically is to consider the graph of $y = f(x)$ and the graphs of $y = \pm x$ on the same coordinate axes.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy example is $f(x) = x^{2/3}$ at $a=0$.  Note the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.  But for $x \neq 0$, the derivative is $f'(x) = (2/3)x^{-1/3}$.  Since this is unbounded in every neighborhood of $0$, neither left nor right limit exist.  So neither left nor right derivative of $f$ exist at $0$.

Comment: If the "two-sided" derivative fails to exist, then so the left or right derivative will fail to exist. Is this true? Like $f(x)=|x|$ at $0$...

Comment: Yes, I just caught that myself.... fixing now

Comment: *Of course, if the "two-sided" derivative ... fails to exist, then so the left or right derivative will fail to exist.* Actually, both unilateral derivatives can exist at a point where the two-sided derivative doesn't exist. An example is $f(x) = |x|$ (absolute value function) at $x=0.$

Comment: Yes, I made a Freshman mistake there... Anyway, I've changed my answer completely :)